# How to make JavaScript ignore line breaks within strings

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

Am trying to input html code with line breaks into a Javascript String, but the line breaks are highlighted as errors, am using sublime text, any work arounds?, the line breaks make the html code more readable.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: complete quotes (' or ") and add "+" at the end of line and begin new text line with a quote or add \n or <br> where you want to break the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a multi-line string literal. In the pre-ES2015 world, you have two options:

1. Concatenate strings:

   ```
   var html =
       "<div>" +
           "Lorem ipsum" +
       "</div>";
   ```
2. Escape the newline:

   ```
   var html =
       "<div>\
           Lorem ipsum\
       </div>";
   ```

ES2015 adds:

3. Use a [*template literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

   ```
   var html = `
       <div>
           Lorem ipsum
       </div>`;
   ```

#3 also has the advantage that you can use placeholders to insert into the template (which becomes a string when evaluated), e.g.:

```
var userName = "Joe Bloggs";
var html = `
    <div>
        Hello ${userName}, how are you?
    </div>`;
```

Comment: the third option was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display a string with line breaks, then Please try something like this

```
var mystr = "this is \n a test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<br/>`?
This is the most standard approach to put line breaks in HTML